# Handling single and double quotes using SED

Tags: regex, shell, sed

Lets say I have a file test.txt which contains the following:

```
This or 
'is nothing or' 
or 
"that or" 
if it is or
```

Now I would like to replace the `or` which are not present in the quotes(either single quote or double quote). I want to achieve this by using `sed`. So my output would be like:

```
 This OR 
 'is nothing or' 
 OR 
 "that or" 
 if it is OR
```

I assume this is achievable by using `awk`, but can anyone do this using `sed`. I am doing this on cygwin.

Comment: did you try anything using sed? or you are looking for ready-made answer?

Comment: I did try, but it is either not replacing in the single quotes or not replacing in the double quotes, but not both

Comment: I know it's late, but I'm having a real hard time trying to figure out what you are asking. How do the `is nothing or` fitting together with `that or` again?

Comment: @Davic C. Rankin - that is just a random example. My intention was to have 3 different flavours of or: 
1. in single quotes
2. in double quotes
3. no quotes

Comment: Why are you looking for `sed` only solution? Why not `perl` or `awk`?

Comment: @anubhava I have one other operation along with this that uses sed extensively, so wanted to club it together. that is why I asked for sed

Comment: @rebelution Why not use perl for that other operation too?

Comment: simply put - I don't have any knowledge of perl :)

Comment: Is that ` at the end of your expected output intended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the answer. We can ignore pattern which occurs in single or double quote by using the hex values of single and double quote.

```
sed -n '/\x22.*or\x22/! { /\x27.*or\x27/! {s/or/OR/g}}' input_file
```